# GIT pull conflict: how come not on any branch?

Tags: git

I have a branch checked out and I edit and commited a file. In the meanwhile, someone else pushed changed to the same file.

When I do a git pull, I see

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: add new line
Applying: create 1 conf
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging <filename>
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in <filename>
Recorded preimage for '<filename>'
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 create 1 conf
When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

I tried to manually resolve the conflict in the file, however I see that I am not on any branch.
I am wondering why this is happening.

```
git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Untracked files:
```

Comment: Did you add the conflicted file `git add file`? and then commit `git commit`?

Comment: @juanpastas commit is not needed there, rebase --continue will do that for you.

Comment: @inger, I thought `git pull` did fetch and then merge, and `git pull --rebase` did fetch and then rebase instead a merge. In the second step, I suppose `git commit` does the commit after merge, but is not clear for me `git rebase --continue` when performing a merge.

Comment: @juanpastas "git pull did fetch and then merge" -unless pull.rebase=true - see my answer below. Based on the output pasted in the question, this was the case: so rebase... for which `rebase --continue` is the next good step. If it was a merge, then this would not apply - you would do a commit after resolving the conflicts as you suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal.  You just need to fix the file and then follow the `rebase` instructions - generally with `--continue`.

You resolve the issue by

1. edit the files to resolve the conflict
2. perform `git checkout --ours -- <filenames>` if you know your version to be good
3. perform `git checkout --theirs -- <filenames>` if theirs is good.

Follow all of these up with `git add <filenames>`.  Note that `--ours` and `--theirs` can be swapped in some cases from what you might expect; so check the file that is actually checked-out if you use options 2 or 3.

Conclude with `git rebase --continue` (which will do the commit for you).  If you do decide to abort be sure to use `git rebase --abort` so that git can get you out of the 'not on any branch' condition.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did a git add, git commit, and then the rebase , which was just leaving me in a detached head state. Seeing Just resolving the conflicts, git add, git rebase --continue, and then git push worked perfectly fine.

Comment: While the answer is quite instructive (and correct) I think it would be good to provide extra background as to *why* the OP got into this situation in the first place, otherwise the answer makes the impression Git requires some mumbo-jumbo to just undo a simple pull. So @user1801669, pay attention to the answer given by inger.

Answer (score 6):

> I am not on any branch. I am wondering why this is happening?

Trying to answer this and help understand what's going on -- *rather than just a recipe to 'stick your head back on' from the headless state*:

- you seem to be using a git config setting (`pull.rebase` or `branch.*rebase`) which directs `git pull` to do a fetch+rebase rather than a fetch+merge
- rebase is basically replaying your local commits on top of the remote branches' head (ie whatever the latest commit there is).. this involves the following:

  1. git retrieves the list of local commits since your last fetch/pull, and the commits the other guys did on the remote branch
  2. in your case it finds out the above 2 have diverged (so not a fast-forward case)
  3. it checks out the latest revision of the remote branch. Note: it doesn't checkout the remote branch itself, that is: doesn't set the HEAD reference to remote/yourbranch as it's forbidden (because it's a readonly mirror of the remote repo, so you cannot update it directly by a commit). That's what it means to be in *headless state*.
  4. it attempts to cherry-pick(replay) your commits one-by-one onto that point, building up a similar history to what you have done(with the same sequence of diffs/patches), except now it's based on the latest and greatest

     4.1. In case any patch results in a conflict during step 4, the process will pause to let you resolve it. That's when you realise you're in a strange state: status says "not on any branch", gitk will show no head label on the latest commit. So just follow the advice git is suggesting: resolve conflicts, stage the changes(git add), then just ..

     4.2. `git rebase --continue` to resume the process (no commit required, git will do it for you). Goto 4. Alternatively, you may want drop you change by `--skip` or if you're too confused, `--abort` will reset everything to where it was before the rebase part.
  5. after all commits are done (that is: patches applied), it moves(resets) yours original  branch reference to this to tip of rebased history(btw,abandoning the original sequence of commits in favour of the replayed history).. So now, you automatically get a brand new HEAD (your branch ref). Headlessness is over, you wouldn't notice have been in that state for a moment

If you happened to use `git config pull.rebase=false` or (branch.*rebase), you would have avoided this scary state (and potentially more conflicts) - however you may get noisier history with a lot of merges instead. (Personally 
It's also possible to switch this off for a single pull by passing `--no-rebase`.

More in depth about rebase: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing .

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination. In my settings, I have
branch.autosetuprebase=always, which basically sets up pull to rebase instead of merge.

Comment: Right, that's the other way, sort of equivalent to pull.rebase.. updating my answer.

Comment: If I do a git checkout --theirs <filename> and git checkout --ours <file name>, do I just need to add and commit, and do a rebase --continue? Whethere I do a commit or not, I still get into DETACHED HEAD. I would also like to know how the context for --ours and --theirs gets swapped? Thanks!

Comment: As said above, you don't need to commit as rebase will do it after adding(staging) your resolution. Well, yes '--ours' and '--theirs' can be confusing at first..The way I like to look at it is: during rebase, you're actually based on the target branch(that's "ours" or "local") onto which your commits(patches) are applied like mini-merges(cherry-picks)- so where you were so far becomes the "remote branch". I'd consider this swapping a relic of the era when git was considered geeky (~=user-unfriendly).Rebase is an advanced concept, the trouble is it still seems to makes sense in a novice setup.

Comment: Here's a "little" one-liner to test rebase conflict in repo1: `git init repo&&(cd repo&& touch 1.txt&&git add .&&git commit -m '1')&&git clone repo repo1&&(cd repo1&&echo a>1.txt&&git commit -a -m 'a')&&(cd repo&&echo b>1.txt&&git commit -a -m 'b')&&cd repo1&&git pull`

Comment: And yes, you're in DETACHED HEAD, until the rebase process is complete. That is, step 4 above -- hope my new update makes it clearer.